# Phone is not getting the update from the app

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app and put it to the play store. The current version on my mobile phone is version 1.5. Now I made some changes and have now version 1.6

The android manifest looks like that

```
<manifest package="de.activevalue.tenthousandfliesmf4a"
    android:versionCode="7"
    android:versionName="1.6" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

So, I uploaded it into the play store. The update is in it. The developer console even says that before I had `Version 6: 1.5` and now I have `Version 7: 1.6` but my phone doesn't update my app and also, when I go on the store entry of the app it doesn't tell me that I can update. What am I doing wrong?! How do I update correctly? I used the same keystore as always and increased the versionCode and VersionName.

Answer (score 2):

How long ago did you put this update?

From my previous experience, when i updated the app, it showed in the next 24hours in the app store as updated-**>When viewed from browser on PC.**

*But in google play app on the phone it sometimes took up to 3 days*...try deleting the cache for google play store on your phone if its not showing up there but you can view the updated version from your PC.

Also the notification for your app updated will show it self to users after certain time, its not immediately, my phones prompts me for updates once a week i think for all the apps i have installed on my phone.

Comment: Hi, on my phone, in the store the app is already updated. I updated the app a couple of hours ago. I'll wait until tomorrow if the app is still not updated. Thanks !